# Python putting . before module name while importing

Tags: python, django

While importing modules in python does it make a difference if we put a "." infront of the module name and does it have an advantage ? 
Example in django docs :

```
from .models import Question
```

Is it different than

```
from models import Question
```

that one ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, without the `.` you mean absolute import in "modern" Python version, and you have relative with the `.` You can read here [PEP 328 -- Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for more details.